# asp.net core 3.1 - Add reference from class library to web application in the same solution

Tags: reference, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an asp.net core 3.1 solution, with web application project and another 2 class library projects.
[files architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cafk.png)

I am trying to add reference from one class library project to the other using Ctrl+".", but it doesn't give an option to do that in the [IntelliSense.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpMLG.png)

1. How can I do the reference without IntelliSense ? (Adding it manually `using CoronaPatients.Core` also not working).
2. How to enable it from the IntelliSense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have just discovered the **right click on the project ->> Add ->> Project Reference...** option, and **check** the project you want to reference to.
But still, why is it not in the IntelliSense ?